wgpu get_mapped_range() returns all 0s
I am using wgpu 0.19 and trying to get the raw data back from a buffer I initialize to put it in an image. I want to do operations on this data before i get it back. However, it's all 0s. I'm quite disgruntled by this. What should I do?
this is my code, using wgpu 0.19 and other libraries at latest version.
use rand::RngCore;
use wgpu::util::DeviceExt;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let ft = async {
        let instance = wgpu::Instance::new(wgpu::InstanceDescriptor {
            backends: wgpu::Backends::all(),
            ..Default::default()
        });
        let (device, queue) = instance
            .request_adapter(&wgpu::RequestAdapterOptions {
                power_preference: wgpu::PowerPreference::default(),
                compatible_surface: None,
                force_fallback_adapter: false,
            })
            .await
            .unwrap()
            .request_device(
                &wgpu::DeviceDescriptor {
                    label: None,
                    required_limits: wgpu::Limits::default(),
                    required_features: wgpu::Features::MAPPABLE_PRIMARY_BUFFERS,
                },
                None,
            )
            .await
            .unwrap();

        let mut noisy_data = [5; 4096 * 4];
        rand::thread_rng().fill_bytes(&mut noisy_data);
        println!("{:?}", &noisy_data[0..10]);
        let rand_buffer = device.create_buffer_init(&wgpu::util::BufferInitDescriptor {
            label: Some("to sort"),
            contents: &noisy_data,
            usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::STORAGE | wgpu::BufferUsages::MAP_READ,
        });
        let (tx, rx) = futures_intrusive::channel::shared::oneshot_channel();
        rand_buffer
            .slice(..)
            .map_async(wgpu::MapMode::Read, move |result| {
                tx.send(result).unwrap();
            });
        device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait);
        rx.receive().await.unwrap().unwrap();
        let rand_buffer: &[u8] = &rand_buffer.slice(..).get_mapped_range();
        println!("{:?}", &rand_buffer[0..10]);
        
    };
    pollster::block_on(ft);
    Ok(())
}

this gives me the following result (the first array is random, second should be the same):
[42, 234, 197, 113, 174, 98, 171, 212, 134, 173]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I know this code has many unnecessary panic points, I am only using this for testing/learning. I have also already looked at similar questions but it seems like I already implemented their fixes. Please help

It appears that the issue was that device.create_buffer_init() doesn't fill the buffer until queue.submit() is run. In other words, device.create_buffer_init() fills the buffer with data using the queue, which was very confusing for me. To fix, just put queue.submit([]) after device.create_buffer_init().
